# Linking a Website to Images in a different Server Domain

Tags: html, image, multiple-domains, imagesource

I am trying to create a site in one domain that would link to image files in another domain.  I am having much difficulty with figuring out how to code out the correct syntax for the  tag.  The images need to be kept secure and NOT in the same drive as the website.  If the images are in a different server domain, what is the correct sourcing syntax to get the images to work?  When I try to put in  "file:///W|/inetpub/wwwroot/Assetcheck/103809.jpg" as the image source in the HTML code and try to run that in a browser, the image comes out blank!  What is the proper method to source image files not within the same drive as the site itself?

Thanks for the help in advance, really appreciated.
Jason

Comment: `http://name-of-the-website-in-different-domain.something/image.ext`

Comment: This is what I have tried as well, but the image still does not work.  It comes out blank in all three internet browsers (IE, Chrome and Firefox).  Is there any other methods of referencing the image between servers?

Comment: Or would anyone know of any security options for folders/files in server domains?  If there is a way to keep the image file secure, then I would be able to put the images in the same location as the site.  I will look for solutions, but just wanted to pop the question to see if anyone has any ideas.  Thanks in advance!